# How to query GA export to BQ schema with hits.customDimensions.index in WHERE clause?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

As of a few days ago, the following query worked fine on BQ with [the schema generated by an export from GA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en):

```
SELECT hits.customDimensions.value
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([88399188.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('20150623'), TIMESTAMP('20150623'))
WHERE hits.customDimensions.index=14
LIMIT 1000
```

Now, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields customDimensions.index and hits.customDimensions.index.
```

Interestingly, the following query works fine (i.e. without the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT hits.customDimensions.value
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([88399188.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('20150623'), TIMESTAMP('20150623'))
LIMIT 1000
```

Also, the following query works fine:

```
SELECT hits.customDimensions.value
FROM [88399188.ga_sessions_20150623]
WHERE hits.customDimensions.index=14
LIMIT 1000
```

Note that the FROM clause is the only difference between this one and the failing query; even though they are supposed to resolve to the exact same query.  Please help!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both customDimensions is REPEATED RECORD, and hits is REPEATED RECORD, and each can repeat independently of the other. Therefore selecting hits.customDimensions.value while filtering on hits.customDimensions.index is not well defined in meaning. If, for example, you want to skip the entire record when non of the hits.customDimensions.index is 14, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT hits.customDimensions.value
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
     [88399188.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('20150623'), TIMESTAMP('20150623')
OMIT RECORD IF EVERY(hits.customDimensions.index != 14)
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Then why does the last query in my question work?  Is it not just as ambiguous?

Comment: Your last query used the same repeated group hits.customDimensions, and picked two fields out of it - index and value. Since they repeat together - there is no ambiguity which value to pick for which index.

Comment: But those are the exact same two fields I used in the first, failing query.  The only difference between the first and last query is the FROM clause that should resolve to the same table.

Comment: I must have misread your original question, for some reason I thought you used mix of customDimensions and hits.customDimensions. If you only use hits.customDimensions - then everything works fine including your first query.

Comment: Looks like there was a temporary bug that is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This anomaly is no longer reproducible.  Though I have not gotten confirmation from Google, I have to assume this was a temporary bug that got fixed.